# Keeping Payos Behind Ear

Tags: payot-sideburns

Any suggestions on how to keep the Peyos behind the ear? They keep "flying" out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hair Styling Gel. Super-hold recommended.

Comment: For Brisker payos?

Answer (score 4):

Hairspray does the trick.

Answer (score -1):

cut them shorter or tuck them under your yarmulke