# Are there any sources that prohibit tucking the peyos behind the ears?

Tags: halacha, payot-sideburns

[Vayikro 19 (27)](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9920#showrashi=true) says:

> You shall not round off the corner of your head, and you shall not
>   destroy the edge of your beard.

Rashi comments,

> “You shall not round off the corner of your head: This refers to
>   someone who [cuts his hair in such a way that he] makes [the hair on]
>   his temples even with that behind his ear and on his forehead [i.e.,
>   the front hairline], thereby causing [the hairline] surrounding his
>   head to become a circle, since the main hairline behind the ears is at
>   a much higher level than [the hair on] his temples. — [Mak. 20B]”

Consider the words “ thereby causing [the hairline] surrounding his head to become a circle.” Someone who has peyos but tucks them behind the ears might also be thought to have a circular hairline. Are there any sources that prohibit tucking the peyos behind the ears?

related: [Keeping Payos Behind Ear](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3169/keeping-payos-behind-ear)

Comment: The Arizal criticizes people who put their peyos behind the ears. This is why Chabad does not put their peyos behind the ears. And instead cuts it to ear lobe length, but I wouldn’t call that a prohibition

Comment: if tucking the "peyos" behind the ear makes it look like one has a circular hairline (and he's an adult) that person probably don't have kosher peyos...

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv - can you provide a source for that statement _The Arizal criticizes people who put their peyos behind the ears._

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv - as well as for _Chabad does not put their peyos behind the ears_ - AFAIK Chabad don't grow long peyos.

Comment: @DannySchoemann yes Chabad doesn't because they follow the arizal that it's only till the ear lobe

Comment: @DannySchoemann it's based on a diyuk from the r Chaim vital reg. The arizal. That he didn't let his payos grow out so as not to mix with the beard. An issue with klipos

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv - check out the בית לחם יהודה on יורה דעה סי' קפ"א where he mentions that Arizal cusotm - not Klipos related, simply not wanting his peyos to mingle with his beard. IIRC. (Which begs the questions where the Chasidim get their long peyos from.)

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv I read somewhere that the Zohar in Nasso actually _instructs_ to tuck the peyos behind the ear. Maybe someone more knowledgeable in the Zohar could verify this?

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify that tucking peyos behind your ear does NOT make your hairline look circular, as you postulate:

> Someone who has peyos but tucks them behind the ears might also be thought to have a circular hairline.

The peyos area is roughly a triangle area as you can see here in the black area.

> ושיעור הפאה הוא מכנגד שער שעל פדחתו ועד למטה מן האוזן מקום שהלחי התחתון יוצא ומתפרד שם וכל רוחב השערות שבמקום זה לא תגע בו יד להעבירם מצד שהוא הכל בכלל פאת הראש‏
>
> <sup>Biur Halocho אפילו מספר ישראל in רנ"א - see below for full text</sup>

[image: peyos area]

If you tuck the hair from this area behind your ear, you do not get a round hairline. Here's what a round hairline looks like:

[image: round hairline]

Here's what it looks like when you tuck your peyos behind your ears - see the 2 kids on the extreme right and left and the Rabbinical looking fellow in the middle - all have their peyos tucked behind their ears - no round hairline in sight.

[image: peyos behind the ear]

[Here's an article](http://www.5tjt.com/read-this-article-and-get-a-torah-mitzvah/) on the subject in English.

So, when you ask:

> Are there any sources that prohibit tucking the peyos behind the ears?

Why would there be?

<sup>That said, R' Chaim Kanievsky שליט"א often berates people who have their payos tucked behind their ears, asking why they are ashamed of their peyos.
 The mystery is why he thinks so, since most of us tuck our **very visible** peyos behind our ears to look neat - we're not ashamed of them and are not hiding them.</sup>

The full text of the Biur Halocho אפילו מספר ישראל in רנ"א - page 82 in a classic Mishna Brura:

> אפילו מספר ישראל - אגב דאיירינן בענין תספורת ראיתי להזכיר ענין אחד מה שאיזה מהמון נכשלין בו בעו"ה והוא בענין איסור דהקפת פאת הראש וכמו שאבאר כי ידוע דעל איסור **הקפת פאת הראש** יש ג"כ לאו בתורה והוא הלאו דלא תקיפו פאת ראשכם וי"א דפאת הראש חמור עוד מפאת זקן דעובר על הלאו אפי' אם מעבירים במספרים כעין תער דהיינו סמוך לבשרו **ושיעור הפאה הוא מכנגד שער שעל פדחתו ועד למטה מן האוזן מקום שהלחי התחתון יוצא ומתפרד שם וכל רוחב השערות שבמקום זה לא תגע בו יד להעבירם מצד שהוא הכל בכלל פאת הראש** ומשם ולמטה מתחלת פאת הזקן וכמבואר כ"ז בש"ע יורה דעה סימן קפ"א ע"ש גם אחד המקיף ואחד הניקף הוא בכלל לאו זה וכמבואר שם ובעו"ה מצוי שמעבירין את הפאות עד סמוך לבשרן ממש ואין משיירין כלל ויש בזה חשש דאורייתא והיה להם לשייר עכ"פ קצת מן הקצת וביותר מזה יש מהבחורים שבעת שהספר מספר ראשו הוא מגלח לו השער שאצל אזנו והוא מחמת שמוטעין שחושבין שפאת הראש נקרא רק מה שאנו קורין פאה ולא כן הוא כאשר כתבנו והוא לאו גמור דאורייתא לד"ה וגם זה הלאו הוא אפילו על הניקף וכנ"ל וע"כ אפילו אם המספר הוא א"י יש לישראל להזהירו שלא יגע בו כלל במקום ההוא וגם במרחץ מותר להפסיק את המספר שלא יגלח במקום ההוא אם יהיו דבריו נשמעין לו וכמבואר לעיל בסימן פ"ד דכדי לאפרושי מאיסורא מותר אפילו במרחץ עיי"ש:‏

Comment: +1 for the picture of Shia LaBeouf... Jk great answer!

Comment: @ezra - never heard of him - it was the first relevant picture I found on Google. :-)

Comment: He's an actor, used to be very popular among young people such as myself. I never really liked him but I could recognize his face any day of the week - I've had friends who adored him

Comment: Rav Chaim kanievsky quotes the Chazon Ish and his father berating people imitating the nations and being embarrassed of ones peyos in his Orchos Yosher

Comment: Also I've seen frum kids with a high hairline so when they tuck their peyos it really looks rounded

Answer (score 0):

There may potentially be a reason to prohibit putting peyos behind the ear, but not for this same issue involved as in cutting off the  peyos entirely. The Medresh Rabbah (ואתחנן פ' יח) says that there are two types of haircuts that fall under the category of darkei emori, which is asur. The medresh describes one of these haircuts as "תפיסת קורצין" (I appologize for potential misspelling) which the Eitz Yosef (one of the primary commentaries on Medresh Rabbah) says is a haircut which cuts the peyos in such a way that there is no obstruction when trying to grab the ear, rather the proper way to have your peyos is over the ear which would create an obstruction, ע"ש.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how strictly "prohibit" is meant in your question - but the Idra Rabba seems to say the **ideal form of them (the hair of the "Peot") goes from over the ears and is part of the beard at large, which surrounds the face and covers down to the core of the heart.** *Rather than a prohibition to tuck them behind the ears it might be a type of bittul Asseh of "walking in His ways" - (however, consider the opening of Rashbi's discussion, "Woe! to he that "extends his hand" - see there)* - and the Zohar greatly praises and emphasizes the enormous power of Pikudin d'Asseh, the positive commandments, to arouse His love and sweeten judgments etc.

First Rashbi explains thirteen Tikkunei Dikna, corrections and formations of the Supernal "Beard" (and the hair of the Peot is included the Beard but not by the name Peot) of the Saba Kadisha. The Friends in turn together reveal another thirteen Tikkunim. Then this is followed by the Nine Tikkunim of the Beard of Zeir Anpin.

---

Zohar III:130b ff.

R' Shimon opened the discussion and said:
Woe to he that extends his hand (destroys/cuts - degrades/**displaces?**?) the Precious Supernal "Beard" of the Saba Kadisha, the most Hidden and Concealed!
...

We have learned in Sifra D'Tzniuta that this (Supernal) "Beard" [which is] the universal faith, **goes forth from** [behind] **the ears and descends encircling the Holy Mouth, descends-rises-and-covers with a (powerful) offering of fine fragrance the whiteness/brightness of (His) glorious (Face). Descending in Shikula ("in measure") it covers down to the core (of the Heart).** This is that Precious Beard of Perfect Faith, within which flow the 13 streams, springs of goodly anointing oil. In thirteen Tikkunim (Corrections/forms) it is mit'taken/established/formed.

**First Tikkun. The hair is mit'taken mil'eila, formed "from above" [i.e. the sides of the head and maybe towards the top of the Face] and originates from that type (tikkun) of His head hear, as it rises in that type [from back] above His ears, and descends in front of the opening of the ears, with one strand in "good measure," until the start of the mouth.**

Second Tikkun. The hair is mit'taken from the head (corner) of the mouth rising over unto the other head of the mouth, in a symmetric form.

Third etc. etc.

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%9B%D7%94#%D7%90%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%90

...

```
פתח ר"ש ואמר:

ווי מאן דאושיט ידוי בדיקנא יקירא עלאה דסבא קדישא טמירא סתימא דכלא (נ"א טמיר וסתים מכלא)
דיקנא דההיא תושבחתא.
דיקנא דסתים ויקיר מכל תקונוי.
דיקנא דלא ידעין עלאין ותתאין.
דיקנא דהיא תושבחתא דכל תושבחין.
דיקנא דלא הוי בר נש נביאה וקדישא דיקרב למחמי ליה.
דיקנא דהיא תלייא בשערוי עד טבורא דלבא. חוורא כתלגא יקירא דיקירין. טמירא דטמירין. מהימנותא דמהימנותא דכלא.

תאנא בצניעותא   [דף קלא ע"א]   דספרא דהאי דיקנא מהימנותא דכלא נפיק מאודנוי ונחית סוחרניה דפומא קדישא ונחי וסליק וחפי בתקרובתא (סגי) דבוסמא טבא. חוורא דיקירא (ס"א דבדיקני'). ונחית (ס"א חוורא יקירא דדיקניה נחית) בשקולא וחפי עד טבורא. הוא דיקנא יקירא מהימנא שלימא דנגדין ביה י"ג נביעין מבועין דמשח רבות טבא בתלת עשר תקונין מתתקנא.

תקונא קדמאה. מתתקן שערא מלעילא ושארי מההוא תקונא דשער רישיה דסליק בתקונוי לעילא מאודנוי ונחית מקמי פתחא דאודנין בחד חוטא בשקולא טבא עד רישא דפומא:

תקונא תנינא מתתקן שערא מרישא דפומא (וסליק) עד רישא אחרא דפומא בתקונא שקיל.  

...
```

---

The "Beard" of Zeir Anpin is formed also **down from above the ears, then up by the Kotzin (locks, maybe corners) in front of the ears,** then down to the mouth corners.

daf 139a

```
תקונא קדמאה. מתתקן שערא מלעילא, ונפיק ההוא ניצוצא בוצינא דקרדינותא, ונפיק מכללא דאוירא דכיא ובטש בתחות שערא דרישא מתחות קוצין דעל אודנין. ונחית מקמי פתחא דאודנין נימי על נימי עד רישא דפומא.
```

---

**(In contrast - and something he did not say about the hair of the Peot),** earlier Rashbi says **the head hairs** should be neat and clean, of a length to the top of the shoulders, covering the back of the neck and **tucked behind the ears.**

daf 129a

```
ותאנא משערוי דב"נ אשתמודע מאי הוא, אי דינא אי בדיוקניה) (ס"א בדיקניה) ובגביני עינוי.

קוצין דשערי תליין בתקוני נקיי כעמר נקא עד כתפוי. עד כתפוי ס"ד אלא עד רישי דכתפי. דלא אתחזי קודלא משום דכתיב "כי פנו אלי עורף ולא פנים". ושערא סליק אבתרוי דאודנין דלא לחפייא עלוי דכתיב "להיות אזניך פקוחות."
```

---

One more consideration - the reason the beard (and its hair of the Peot) is not mentioned in the Torah (and not that much discussed in Halakhic literature; obviously "do not destroy the Peah of your Beard" is mentioned - so maybe he is referring to the fact that the Beard itself is not mentioned - only hinted to and indirectly) is precisely because it's "more precious and hidden than anything else."

daf 132b

We find - the Beard of the King, Atika, is the most Precious of everything. All in one it's Hidden and Precious. And because it's more Precious and Secret than anything else - that's why it's nowhere mentioned in the Torah! (other sefarim: "not mentioned in the Torah") - and not revealed. ...

אשתכח דיקנא דמלכא עתיקא יקירא מכלא. כלא בחד איהו טמירא ויקירא. ובגין דאיהו יקירא וטמירא מכלא - לא אדכר ביה באתר דאורייתא (ס"א לא אדכר באורייתא) ולא אתגלייא. ומה דיקנא אתגלייא? דיקנא דכהנא רבא עלאה. ומהאי דיקנא נחית לדיקנא דכהנא רבא דלתתא.